# Android view does not show up

Tags: android, view, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have this layout in my application, the problem is, the `ImageView` which has the ID `overlay`, does not show up over the others, and when I check the layout with Android SDK Hierarchy viewer tool, that `ImageView` has 0 height, placed at the bottom of the layout. What am I missing? Or what is the reason?

Thanks.

**NOTE:** This problem does not occur when I replace that view with a `Button` in the same condition. But it occurs with a `View`, or `ImageView`.

**EDIT:** I am using mentioned `ImageView` to make the whole view a bit reddish, and I'm using it as a `ListView` item.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#77ff0000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try to remove android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

Comment: You can't show one view two side at the same time i.e. not right and not left.(as you have set the alignParentLeft and alignParentRight,top,bottom at the same time ).

Comment: Works fine for me - try cleaning the project once - Well basically for me the Transparent Red Image in the foreground covers over the items behind it - is this what you want ?

Comment: I have set a source for the images/ given a dummy text for each of them

Comment: @Slartibartfast: ye, that's what I want! I tried cleaning and done all these kinds of things, but nothing changed. please take a look at the edit note I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I see with your xml(with dummy text and image)

[image]

1.) Is this what you want? I ll be surprised if you are not seeing this

2.) If this forms your individual list item xml then in your main list xml make sure you have this as your parameters

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

or you might not see the edges of this item (the text and the image and you might see only the red overlay, or the text and image might get overlapped)

**EDIT:**

If this is what you want - so that the list item now forms a list item like state then

[image]

Modify your code to

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/panda" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Stack Overflow"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#77ff0000" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Change Image and text to what you want at runtime

Comment: about 1) yeah, that is what I want to see, but I don't.
about 2) already it is.
about Edit part) this fixes the problem, I know, and there are other ways to do it too. But I am wondering why my code is not working. thanks for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#77ff0000" />
```

In imageview you cant  assign all the alignment type together either
 [1].top with right or left
 [2].bottom with right or left.

Comment: I have a question if width and height is fill parent is it necessary to align ?

Comment: No not necessary , but looking at this xml code if you fill parent last imageview "@+id/overlay" 's height and width, it will definitely overlap another 2 views.

Comment: Not working, and I do not agree with you about your description.

Comment: @KeyhanAsghari your question seems unclear. Also, you say `ImageView is a view with 0 height`, what height you expect when you are not setting any image for the ImageView? Its always preferable to set the resource/image to check the exact output.

Comment: @KeyhanAsghari also by using `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image"` at the topmost view of your parent layout at that time `@+id/image` id is unknown as you are declaring your ImageView after the TextView.

Comment: @LalitPoptani: I expect full height because I am setting `fill_parent`. and `ImageView` does not need to have a image to be displayed, it can be seen when it hasn't any `android:src` and has just a `android:background`.

Comment: @LalitPoptani: that `ImageView` is declared above in text, and does not need to be declared again. see developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Comment: @KeyhanAsghari have specs and check again. Is ImageView having id as `@id/image` declared above the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need to do is `android:layout_alignParentCenter="true"` 
instead of

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

@ NOTE: Everything comes under View which is a parent class whether its a Button or ImageView

Answer (score -1):

The height of the imageView is 0 because you havent set any source. Fixing these bugs you can try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#77ff0000" />
```

Comment: its not necessary that views can be referenced after they have been declared. if you use + in front of id Even view below it can also be referenced

Comment: check this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html